# Function running twice using setdelay

Tags: javascript, jquery, tampermonkey

My function is running twice , I tried using boolean value to stop it but it doesn't work, here is my code :

```
     window.onload = function(){
   setTimeout(addbutton, 2940) // Please increase it if it doesn't work, it doesn't work well if your connection is too long
};
function addbutton(){
var hreflink = "/admin/users/delete/"+id;
var Reportuser = document.getElementsByClassName("sg-button sg-button--solid-light sg-button--full-width");
var x = Reportuser.length-1
Reportuser[x].insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', '<button id=button class="sg-button sg-button--solid-mint sg-button--small sg-button"><span class="sg-button__text">Delete</span></button>');
console.log("%cButton added","color: blue; font-size: 20px");

function myFunction() {
window.location.href = hreflink;
}
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", myFunction);

}
```

Comment: there is a Syntax error, a missing `}` for `addbutton` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refactored and converted your code to a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) using [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation). The timeout works, once. If you are experiencing problems with connection times, maybe you should check [async functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

```js
setTimeout(addbutton, 500);

document.addEventListener("click", handle); 

function handle(evt) {
  if (evt.target.dataset.clickable) {
    console.clear();
    return console.log("Yes! It's clicked!");
  }
  return true;
}

function addbutton() {
  [...document.querySelectorAll(".sg-button")].pop()
    .insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", `<button data-clickable="1">Delete</button>`);
  console.log("button added to last div.sg-button ...");
}
```

```css
.sg-button {
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  padding: 0.2rem;
  width: 5rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.sg-button button {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="sg-button sg-button--solid-light sg-button--full-width">1</div>
<div class="sg-button sg-button--solid-light sg-button--full-width">2</div>
```